# How to make the appendixes?

Tags: tables, floats, chapters, appendix

I'm writing a book where the appendix is located after the bibliography. If I place the appendix after the \backmatter, it eliminates the number or letter of the appendix, affecting the numbering of the tables or figures. If I use \chapter*, it has the same effect. How do I not number the annex and do not eliminate the numbering (A.1,...) of the tables and figures in the annex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you considered not using the `\backmatter` directive?

Comment: But, how do I not number the appendix and do not eliminate the numbering (A.1,...) of the tables and figures in the appendix.

Comment: Try \usepackage{appendix} - https://ctan.org/pkg/appendix?lang=en